# C++ and left/right shift operators on a boolean

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

Consider the following program that tests the result of shift operators on boolean converted back to a boolean:

```
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    std::cout<<"right shift: bool/bool"<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<"false << false = "<<bool(false << false)<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<"false << true = "<<bool(false << true)<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<"true << false = "<<bool(true << false)<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<"true << true = "<<bool(true << true)<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<"right shift: bool/unsigned int"<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<"false << 0U = "<<bool(false << 0U)<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<"false << 1U = "<<bool(false << 1U)<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<"false << 2U = "<<bool(false << 2U)<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<"false << 100U = "<<bool(false << 100U)<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<"true << 0U = "<<bool(true << 0U)<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<"true << 1U = "<<bool(true << 1U)<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<"true << 2U = "<<bool(true << 2U)<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<"true << 100U = "<<bool(true << 100U)<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<"right shift: bool/int"<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<"false << -100 = "<<bool(false << -100)<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<"false << -2 = "<<bool(false << -2)<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<"false << -1 = "<<bool(false << -1)<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<"false << 0 = "<<bool(false << 0)<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<"false << 1 = "<<bool(false << 1)<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<"false << 2 = "<<bool(false << 2)<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<"false << 100 = "<<bool(false << 100)<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<"true << -100 = "<<bool(true << -100)<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<"true << -2 = "<<bool(true << -2)<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<"true << -1 = "<<bool(true << -1)<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<"true << 0 = "<<bool(true << 0)<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<"true << 1 = "<<bool(true << 1)<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<"true << 2 = "<<bool(true << 2)<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<"true << 100 = "<<bool(true << 100)<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<"left shift: bool/bool"<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<"false >> false = "<<bool(false >> false)<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<"false >> true = "<<bool(false >> true)<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<"true >> false = "<<bool(true >> false)<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<"true >> true = "<<bool(true >> true)<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<"left shift: bool/unsigned int"<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<"false >> 0U = "<<bool(false >> 0U)<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<"false >> 1U = "<<bool(false >> 1U)<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<"false >> 2U = "<<bool(false >> 2U)<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<"false >> 100U = "<<bool(false >> 100U)<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<"true >> 0U = "<<bool(true >> 0U)<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<"true >> 1U = "<<bool(true >> 1U)<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<"true >> 2U = "<<bool(true >> 2U)<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<"true >> 100U = "<<bool(true >> 100U)<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<"left shift: bool/int"<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<"false >> -100 = "<<bool(false >> -100)<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<"false >> -2 = "<<bool(false >> -2)<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<"false >> -1 = "<<bool(false >> -1)<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<"false >> 0 = "<<bool(false >> 0)<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<"false >> 1 = "<<bool(false >> 1)<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<"false >> 2 = "<<bool(false >> 2)<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<"false >> 100 = "<<bool(false >> 100)<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<"true >> -100 = "<<bool(true >> -100)<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<"true >> -2 = "<<bool(true >> -2)<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<"true >> -1 = "<<bool(true >> -1)<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<"true >> 0 = "<<bool(true >> 0)<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<"true >> 1 = "<<bool(true >> 1)<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<"true >> 2 = "<<bool(true >> 2)<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<"true >> 100 = "<<bool(true >> 100)<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

It produces the following output on my computer:

```
right shift: bool/bool
false << false = 0 // Well defined
false << true = 0 // Well defined
true << false = 1 // Well defined
true << true = 1 // Well defined

right shift: bool/unsigned int
false << 0U = 0 // Well defined
false << 1U = 0 // Well defined
false << 2U = 0 // ?
false << 100U = 0 // Undefined behaviour
true << 0U = 1 // Well defined
true << 1U = 1 // Well defined
true << 2U = 1 // ?
true << 100U = 0 // Undefined behaviour

right shift: bool/int
false << -100 = 0 // Undefined behaviour
false << -2 = 0 // Undefined behaviour
false << -1 = 0 // Undefined behaviour
false << 0 = 0 // Well defined
false << 1 = 0 // Well defined
false << 2 = 0 // ?
false << 100 = 0 // Undefined behaviour
true << -100 = 0 // Undefined behaviour
true << -2 = 0 // Well defined
true << -1 = 0 // Well defined
true << 0 = 1 // Well defined
true << 1 = 1 // Well defined
true << 2 = 1 // ?
true << 100 = 0  // Undefined behaviour

left shift: bool/bool
false >> false = 0 // Well defined
false >> true = 0 // Well defined
true >> false = 1 // Well defined
true >> true = 0 // Well defined

left shift: bool/unsigned int
false >> 0U = 0 // Well defined
false >> 1U = 0 // Well defined
false >> 2U = 0 // ?
false >> 100U = 0  // Undefined behaviour
true >> 0U = 1 // Well defined
true >> 1U = 0 // Well defined
true >> 2U = 0 // ?
true >> 100U = 0  // Undefined behaviour

left shift: bool/int
false >> -100 = 0  // Undefined behaviour
false >> -2 = 0  // Undefined behaviour
false >> -1 = 0  // Undefined behaviour
false >> 0 = 0 // Well defined
false >> 1 = 0 // Well defined
false >> 2 = 0 // ?
false >> 100 = 0  // Undefined behaviour
true >> -100 = 0  // Undefined behaviour
true >> -2 = 1  // Undefined behaviour
true >> -1 = 1  // Undefined behaviour
true >> 0 = 1 // Well defined
true >> 1 = 0 // Well defined
true >> 2 = 0 // ?
true >> 100 = 0  // Undefined behaviour
```

The C++ standard part 5.8 `expr.shift` describes the behaviour of the shift operator, but I want to be sure to understand it well. Consequently, I would like to know for each line I test, whether the line is "well defined behaviour and implementation independent", or whether it's "implementation dependent/undefined behaviour".

EDIT: I pre-filled it, so I just need a confirmation, and an answer about the case where I don't know (noted `?`)

Comment: Far too broad. You want us to enumerate every possible combination of these operators? No. When you have a concrete question about a concrete piece of code that you've _actually_ written, and need confirmation that it's well-defined, ask us then.

Comment: I don't get what's unclear about *The behavior is undefined if the right operand
is negative, or greater than or equal to the length in bits of the promoted left operand*. All of the ones with negative shifts immediately get eliminated, and promotions are covered elsewhere, but the `int` and `unsigned` shifts are already unaffected.

Comment: The shift operators are *defined* for integral numbers, and `bool` is not an integral value; it must be converted to an integral value before the shift is applied.  So, this issue is fundamentally based on the rules of conversion.

Comment: First of all: don't use C casts in C++ and `std::endl` not that often (every time a flush). Your code can be much shorter without casts, just one `std::cout` and `\n` instead of `std::endl`. Furthermore it's clear that booleans get converted to integers, usually `false = 0` and `true = 1` and with `char` as data type.

Comment: Typical example of case I'm not sure about : `false >> 2` or `false << 2`.

Comment: @Vincent Shifting `00000000` right or left is still zero, just 0 bits will be added.

Comment: @Youka. Yeah, but technically, I need 1 bit to store a boolean. Integral promotion happens, but do I have the guarantee that I will end up with an integer of at least 2 bits on every possible platform? And if it's not the case, then I use a shift operator with a value higher than the number of bits in the shifted value, which leads to an undefined behaviour.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I edited the post with what of I understand from the standard (still need a check, because I am not sure that 0 >> 100 is an undefined behaviour for example). So only few cases remains questionable for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are only a few cases to consider. We call `E1` the promoted left operand and `E2` the promoted right operand. The **undefined behavior** cases are:

- If `E2` "is negative, or greater than or equal to the length in bits of" `E1`
- In `E1 << E2`, if `E1` is signed and either
  a. negative
  b. E1×2<sup>E2</sup> is not "representable
  in the corresponding unsigned type of the result type"

The **implementation-defined behavior** cases are:

- In `E1 >> E2`, if `E1` "has a signed type and a negative value."

Everything else is well-defined.

---

Your cases marked with a `?` are all well-defined. `E1` and `E2` are never negative, and `E2` is nowhere near 32, so there's no concern for overflow. All are well-defined `int`s.

Comment: What guarantee do I have regarding to the implicit conversion of E1 (for example in the true << true case)? Am I sure that I will end up with at least a 32 bits integer on every possible platform?

Comment: @Vincent It's well-defined. Both `true`s are promoted to the `int` `1`. `1 << 1` does not fit any of the undefined behavior cases. So we get the `int` `2`.

Comment: Section 5.8 of the C++ 14 draft standard.  I find it interesting that (for sufficiently large n)  `x <<= n;` is undefined but `while(n--) x <<= 1;` is well defined.

Comment: @Speed8ump: In some cases, it might be preferable to have a 32-bit machine trap e.g. `x<<n` with n==32 than to have it yield `x` [note that having it yield 0 would on many machines require extra code].  All actions where trapping would be a valid behavior, with IIRC the sole exception of narrowing integer type coercions, are regarded as UB even if 99.99% of implementations have historically had one of two specific behaviors.